# What's another word for "not" honed talent?

Tags: idiom-requests, metaphors, figures-of-speech, figurative

I was looking for a metaphorical phrase that sort of fits along the lines of honing a hidden/unapparent talent. I can't quite place my finger on it, but I remember one that goes something like trying to purify (not sure what's the word) a mineral/rock/stone into a form that is beautiful (i.e. diamonds).

Comment: "Diamond in the rough"?

Comment: Here's a [dictionary reference](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diamond%20in%20the%20rough) to the above phrase (if need be)..

Comment: Your question title is in opposition to the question you ask. Please adjust one or the other. Then it may be appropriate to accept @Dillard draws answer once it is expanded to include a relevant definition.